# Repeat function takin previous result of this function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
var x = function (a) { return a + a/4 - 600}
```

I have a function that does something.
So now my goal is to repeat this function 12 times with an argument used from previous operation;
Let's say initial ammount is 5000;
So

```
`x(5000) = 5650;
x(5650) =6462.5;
x(6462.) =...;
```

and this should be repeated 12 times;
So how can this be done in code?
 `

Comment: Ever heard of loops? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly the easiest way would be to use a `for` loop:

```
var x = function(a) { return a + a/4 - 600 },
    v = 5000;

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    v = x(v);
}

console.log(v);
```

Comment: thanks ))) i just over thought myself..))

Answer (score 0):

I'd not recommend doing something like this, but instead of a loop you could use recursion:

```
var x = function(42.34, 12);

----
function(double a, int maxSize)
{ 
   a = ((a + a) / (4 - 600));
   if(maxSize>0){
      maxSize--;
      return function(a,maxSize);
   }else{
       return a;
    }
 }
```

(just pseudocode)